# Compile Opencv from Source Code Mac Os X Maverick

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv, osx-mavericks

I am trying to compile OpenCv from source code on mac os. I installed tbb, openni, freeglut and qt from macport.

I use this command:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-m64 \
-D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m64 -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 -D WITH_TBB=ON \
-D TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/local/include/tbb -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/local \
-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON  -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D WITH_OPENNI=ON -D OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/local/include/ni \
-D WITH_QT=ON ..
```

I have many problems:

1. It does not find QT (My path dir is /Users/morpheus/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/)
2. It does not find OPENNI
3. If I exclude QT and then I try to compile I receive this error:

   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/include/tbb/../lib'
   ld: library not found for -ltbb
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: can you run `ccmake` ?

Comment: Yes, but nothing change :(